# Extract data part in log file

Tags: python, pandas

I am analysing data from log file. My log file is like this :

```
[2018-07-13 03:04:57] production.DEBUG: No problem MemId: 000MemId or CardNo 
There is no staff information
MemId: 2956144 without the bird - file; mbs
There is no staff information
There is no staff information
[2018-07-13 03:06:07] production.DEBUG: No problem MemId: 00mem_id or CardNo
```

And I want to create a DataFrame in pandas. My expected result :

```
TimeStand           Screen           Level         messenger
2018-07-13 03:04:57 production  DEBUG    No problem MemId...staff information
2018-07-13 03:06:07 production  DEBUG    No problem MemId:  00mem_id or CardNo
```

Like this :

[image: result]

I thought of using Regular Expression, But I am a beginner with Python.

Comment: Please provide us with the code that you are currently working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the code, you have not specified much, but you will get an idea how to use regex and you will be able to manipulate it.
also strip some characters by using googling str.strip.

```
import re
import pandas as pd



st= '[2018-07-13 03:04:57] production.DEBUG: No problem MemId: 000MemId or CardNo There is no staff information MemId: 2956144 without the bird - file; mbs There is no staff information here is no staff information [2018-07-13 03:06:07] production.DEBUG: No problem MemId: 00mem_id or CardNo [2018...etc]'


timelist=re.findall('\[\w\S*\s\w*\S*]',st)
df=pd.DataFrame({'TimeStand': timelist})
screenlist=re.findall(r'\bproduction\b',st)
df['Screen']=screenlist
levellist=re.findall(r'\bDEBUG\b',st)
df['Level']=levellist
messengerlist=re.findall(r'\: .*?\[',st)
df['Messenger']=messengerlist
```

Output looks like this-

```
TimeStand      Screen  Level  \
0  [2018-07-13 03:04:57]  production  DEBUG   
1  [2018-07-13 03:06:07]  production  DEBUG   

                                           Messenger  
0  : No problem MemId: 000MemId or CardNo There i...  
1           : No problem MemId: 00mem_id or CardNo [
```

Comment: Hi After your file , I need add "[". So It don't true

Comment: thats what i said , use str.strip to remove [ and : in those columns and you're set.

Comment: Hi , If the Screen's value is not just Production, it may be another value. And I'm trying to write a regular expression for this part but I haven't done it yet

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution.
My code is :

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import pyes # For documentation around pyes.es : https://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/references/pyes.es.html
import requests
import  numpy as np
import datetime
import inspect
import re


v = open(r"C:/laravel-2019-06-01.log","r",encoding='utf-8-sig')


st = v.read()

st = st + '[2018-07-14]'

st = st.replace('\n',' ')

timelist=re.findall('\d{4}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2} \d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2}',st)
df=pd.DataFrame({'TimeStand': timelist})
screenlist=re.findall(r'\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2}\].*?\.',st)
df['TimeStand'] = df['TimeStand'].str.strip('][')
df['Screen']=screenlist
df['Screen'] = df['Screen'].map(lambda x: str(x)[10:])
df['Screen'] = df['Screen'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1])
levellist=re.findall(r'\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2}\].*?\..*?\:',st)
df['Level']=levellist
df['Level'] = df['Level'].map(lambda x: str(x)[21:])
df['Level'] = df['Level'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1])
messengerlist=re.findall(r'\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2}\].*?\..*?\: .*?\[\d{4}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2}',st)
df['Messenger']=messengerlist
df['Messenger']  = np.where(df['Level']=='ERROR',df['Messenger'].map(lambda x: str(x)[27:]),np.where(df['Level']=='DEBUG',df['Messenger'].map(lambda x: str(x)[27:]),np.where(df['Level']=='CRITICAL',df['Messenger'].map(lambda x: str(x)[30:]),np.where(df['Level']=='ALERT',df['Messenger'].map(lambda x: str(x)[27:]),np.where(df['Level']=='NOTICE',df['Messenger'].map(lambda x: str(x)[28:]),np.where(df['Level']=='INFO',df['Messenger'].map(lambda x: str(x)[26:]),np.where(df['Level']=='WARNING',df['Messenger'].map(lambda x: str(x)[29:]),df['Messenger'].map(lambda x: str(x)[31:]))))))))

df['Messenger']  = df['Messenger'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-11])

print(df)
```

I hope that this solution will help those who need it.
Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to start reading the code:

```
import pandas as pd
TimeStand, Screen, Level, messenger = []
log = open('log.txt', 'r')
for line in log:
    if ....:
         TimeStand.append(...)
    elif ....:
         Screen.append(...)
 df = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStand': TimeStand, 'Screen': Screen, 'Level': Level, 'messenger': messenger
```